# JQuery/JQuery-ui and internet explorer 9: change, isvisible, datepicker and timepicker don't work

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, internet-explorer-9

I have:

- some divs that are showed/hidden according to a radio button selection;
- some input fields that are showed if a label is visible;
- an input field that fires a datepicker;
- an input field that fires a timepicker.

For all of that I use JQuery and JQuery UI and all works with Firefox and Chrome, but not with IE 9.

I use this libs:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.9.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css" />
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.8.2.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.9.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.ui.datepicker-it.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-ui-timepicker-addon.js"></script>
```

**EDIT**
This works:

```
 <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=7,IE=8" />
```

also if it changes my layout.

Is there a way to use it only for IE9?